# React native card list , tap to expand to full screen

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I want to create a card list(like Facebook newsfeed) in react native  and that i can also tap on it to expand to fullscreen (into a view like Instagram  stories )

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

here is the code:\

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
 Platform,
 StyleSheet,
 Text,
 View
 } from 'react-native';
import { CardList } from 'react-native-card-list';

const cards = [
{
  id: "0",
  title: "Starry Night",
  picture: require('./assets/expo.symbol.white.png'),
  content: <Text>Starry Night</Text>
},
{
  id: "1",
  title: "Wheat Field",
  picture: require('./assets/icon.png'),
  content: <Text>Wheat Field with Cypresses</Text>
},
 {
  id: "2",
  title: "Bedroom in Arles",
  picture: require('./assets/expo.symbol.white.png'),
  content: <Text>Bedroom in Arles</Text>
 }
]

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
 render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <CardList cards={cards} />
     </View>
  );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center',
   backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
   }
})
```

here is the update:

```
<View style={styles.modalContainer}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text>Jason Brown</Text>
        </View>
        <Image source={picture} style={styles.image} resizeMode="cover" />
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <View style={styles.footerContent}>
            <Text
              style={[styles.text, this.state.selected === "like" && styles.bold]}
              ref={this.likeRef}
              onLayout={this.handleMeasure("like", this.likeRef)}
            >
              Like
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={[styles.text, this.state.selected === "comment" && styles.bold]}
              ref={this.commentRef}
              onLayout={this.handleMeasure("comment", this.commentRef)}
            >
              Comment
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={[styles.text, this.state.selected === "share" && styles.bold]}
              ref={this.shareRef}
              onLayout={this.handleMeasure("share", this.shareRef)}
            >
              Share
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Animated.View>
  </View>
```

https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/modal-card

if this help you, mark as the correct answer.

Comment: I wanted the card to expand to the exact fullscreen(as in popup) and contain the image on the card itself

Comment: here is an example: https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/modal-card

Comment: if ypu and to something like stories take this link: https://github.com/codedailyio/teach/tree/instagramSwiper